# Inverting function variables

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

The original equation is a function of x. However, I want to invert the function and get an expression of x in terms of y.

```
Solve[y == (a x + b)/Exp[x^2], x]
InverseFunction[y == (a x + b)/Exp[x^2], x]
```

I've tried `Solve` and `InverseFunction`, but they both turned out to be futile.

Comment: `e` should be `E`,or `e^x^2` should be `Exp[x^2]`

Comment: I edited the code. Still, it doesn't work

Comment: Did you read the error message? `This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.`

Comment: Yes, I've read that. And I've been trying different ways to solve it. Without the denominator, `Solve` Woks fine in inversing the function. However, When the denominator term comes into the equation, the above-mentioned error comes. Could you direct me in the right direction to resolve it?

Comment: One reason InverseFunction doesn't work is because your function is not invertible. For example, for a=1, you can plot it to see Plot[( x + 1)/Exp[x^2], {x, -5, 5}] where one y value corresponds to multiple x values.

Comment: First, you can divide everything by `a`, introduce `y1=y/a` and study the problem with one variable `b/a`. Second, the important question is: "What are you going to do with your solution, provided you have obtained it?" May it be that an approximate analytical solution will be OK with you? If yes, then what are the limits of variation of `b/a`? Can it be that you only need to plot it for various `b/a` values? If yes, then what is the range of `x`?